# Digital Content and Google Checkout

Tags: php, google-checkout

I have integrated Google Checkout to my payment system with the use of php code provided on the Google Official site.

Now I need to add Digital Content to the Cart. I have checked the Cart and couldn't find any direct function or example for achieving this.

Please suggest the method to add Digital Content to Google Checkout

Answer (score 0):

The doc below lists several options to include digital delivery in Checkout API Requests:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Digital_Delivery.html